# content deleted from angolia after quickedit or frontend edit of post

Tags: wordpress, algolia

Having an issues with the angolia wordpress plugin regarding content.

When I create a post (standard wp or custom post type) content is indexed and visible when I perform a search using angolia.

When I open and edit the post from wp backend changes in content are updated and visible in angolia searches.

However if I quickedit the post from backend, content is deleted (in angolia). Same thing happens if I edit the content from front-end using a plugin for that purpose.

After content is deleted in angolia its no longer visible when I perform a search using angolia.

However as soon as I update the post from wp backend everything is fine again.

Please advice.

Thank you
Søren

Comment: This question is better suited for Angolia support: https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/search-by-algolia-instant-relevant-results

Comment: Are you using any kind of plugin for the quick edit?
It should pick up the changes properly unless a plugin hooks into the native behaviour disallowing the plugin to catch the changes.

All relevant hooks used by the plugin are here: https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-wordpress/blob/master/includes/watchers/class-algolia-post-changes-watcher.php

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

In order to let you fully understand the issue I've created a screen-capture for you to download (www.transfernow.net/88hl85r5c849). It's based on a custom posttype (cm glossary) but I could have used a standard posttype instead - the result would have been the same.

I believe the problem might be related to the fact that "The data for the post is stored in $_POST, $_GET or the global $post_data, depending on how the post was edited" see (https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post).

For frontend editing I'm using "WP User Frontend Pro"